# How to disable the light bulb in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I love Visual Studio Code but I hate the little lightbulb. It seems to clash with the dropdown when you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> on word.

How do you disable the lightbulb in Visual Studio Code?

Just to clarify - I always use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>. But on the first time when I try to navigate down the drop down menu the menu disappears and the lightbulb re-appears. I then have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> again to go down the drop down list and get the selection I want. I just want to disable the lightbulb itself, not other functionality such as the quick fixes.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There's a new option that you can use to disable that. Go to your settings file and add:

```json
"editor.lightbulb.enabled": false
```

Comment: I can breathe again

Comment: @skinnedpanda I was thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 51):

Go to: > File > Preferences > Settings

Enter "bulb"

Click on the checkmark to remove it.

[image: vscode settings]

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me that the arrangement of the lightbulb has changed since the answers above. In my version of VS Code, the easiest way to disable or enable the lightbulb is to just type lightbulb on the Setting search bar.

1. Go to Setting
2. Type "lightbulb" or "bulb" on the Setting's search bar,
3. Check or uncheck the "Enable the code action lightbulb in the
   editor"

If you don't want to use the search bar: go to

1. File >  Preferences > Settings > Text editor

Then scroll down the list to find "Enable the code action lightbulb in the editor". Check or uncheck as you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean. You want to disable the visual element of the lightbulb? Or you want to eliminate "quickFix" altogether?

There is this keybinding which triggers the same action as the lightbulb:

```
{ 
    "key": "ctrl+.",
    "command": "editor.action.quickFix",
    "when": "editorHasCodeActionsProvider && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly" 
}
```

If you are wanting to disable the keyboard shortcut you could do that by adding this line to keybindings.json

```
"key": "ctrl+.", "command": ""
```

If you want something ELSE mapped to "ctrl+.", then you can put that command in the command above.

If you're wanting to disable the lightbulb itself from appearing, I don't think that is possible.

Comment: thanks - please see updated question - I just want to disable the lightbulb which appears regardless of the "Ctrl+." quickfix and seems to interfere with it

Comment: From what I understand, you type something, press 'ctr+.', press the down arrow to make a selection but the menu disappears, and you have to press 'ctr+.' again, but this time pressing the down arrow works? If so, that sounds like a vscode bug to me