# Turn off light bulbs in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a strong dislike for the light bulbs in VS Code.  Is it possible to turn them off, and if so how? I still want to be able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> for refactoring.

[image: VS Code C# Light Bulbs are Annoying!]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable the light bulb in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39485506/how-to-disable-the-light-bulb-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can't.

There is an Open Issue on Github about that

[Option to disable quick fix #27961](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/27961)